# DllImport в зависимости от условия

Tags: c#

Нужно подгружать разные нативные либы в зависимости от значения некоторой функции. Но название dll, которое указывается в DllImport, const, т.е. должно быть известно на момент компиляции.
Как это можно обойти?

Comment: LoadLibrary, может, использовать?

Comment: Хотелось бы обойтись P\Invoke

Comment: Наверное, вот так: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jonathanswift/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c/

Comment: @arrowd что является оберткой на LoadLibrary...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну поинформативнее, согласитесь?

Comment: @arrowd Я бы сказал, что добавлена куча костылей для вызова системной API-функции ;-)

Comment: Без LoadLibrary никак, `DllImport` разрешается на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Ну да, это всё не то. Так я и сам умею, но в моем случае, работу это прилично усложнит.